# Angular material html not working with export to excel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material, export-to-excel

```
<md-card class="no-padding-card" id= "exportthis">
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
            <span class="md-title text-center">I am a card,export Me to Excel</span>
        </md-card-header-text>
        <md-card-content>
        </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

On a button click event i am doing this,

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=exportthis]').html()));
```

But it is exporting the HTML code instead of HTML Card,
I also tried `FileSaver.js` `blob` and `Saveas` method, but it is also working same,
Any help would be appreciable, Thank you.